# How to export a remote java webstart app thru WAN?

Tags: java

I've got the following problem.

A client is looking for better latency to access a forex trading java web app (.jnlp) that is stored on a third party server. I can provide him access to one of our servers (running linux) that is geographicaly closer to the trading portal (rather than connecting directly to the trading server, less latency, which is critical to the client).

I'm trying to find a way to 'export' the web app interface (basically a simple window) back to the client without having to export the full desktop (using vnc, x export, etc). The client is new to linux and a 'one-click' solution would be the best.

Client is running Windows based OS, Server that will export him the java web app is running linux (debian).

What would be the best mix of technologies to get started ?

Comment: Since it's a webstart application, why can't your client just run that java application on his own computer - as that's the whole point with a webstart app? What's the need for exporting only the window back to the client ?

Comment: Latency is the concern. The client will use auto-trading strategies which needs to have the best latency, we can provide this since we are in the same location as the trading server; the client can be anywhere in the world (thus making latency an issue). Hope you got the 'idea'. thx

Comment: i heard about 'vncjlgpl' which seems to export java to vnc, but to be honest i'm kinda very newbie to java, if there was a way to run the trading app inside vncj that would solve the problem, i guess ...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually need is not better latancy to the jnlp app itself (it is propably insignificant really how long the app needs to start up).

You want lower latancy for the communication between the app and the trading server. Which means the machine on which the app **runs**, needs a broad/fast connection to the trading server.

This means any remote desktop application might be a solution to your problem.

(TeamViewer for example allows you to only share a single application (and not the whole desktop). Runs on linux using wine, but I'm not aware of all the compatibility issues.)